# Change location of .ido.last history file in Emacs on Windows

Tags: emacs, ido-mode

Using Emacs with ido mode enabled on Windows, Emacs tries to save a history file .ido.last when exiting. The file is located in C:/.ido.last, but it fails with a permission denied message. This is strange since I actually have access to that folder. However:

Is there a command to change the directory where the .ido.last file gets saved?

Comment: Remove `C:\.emacs` (or `C:\_emacs`), and Emacs will default to the more modern default of `C:\Users\[username]\Application Data`. It only uses `C:\` as the location of such files if it finds a .emacs there, to be backward compatible with old Emacs versions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Short answer: `(setq ido-save-directory-list-file "/some/file/name")`.

Long answer:

I keep all the little files that remember Emacs's state in a single directory under the `user-emacs-directory`.  I'm not sure what this is on Windows, but I think it's `C:\Users\<username>\Application Data\.emacs.d\`.  On Unix, it's `~/.emacs.d/`.  The variable `user-emacs-directory` should be defined by Emacs, no need to set it.

```
(setq emacs-persistence-directory (concat user-emacs-directory "persistence/"))
(unless (file-exists-p emacs-persistence-directory)
    (make-directory emacs-persistence-directory t))
(setq ido-save-directory-list-file (concat emacs-persistence-directory
                                           "ido-last"))
```

You may want to look at the `no-littering` package, which sets better default locations for files like this.